# How to center text along Kinetic.TextPath with kineticjs

Tags: kineticjs

Is there a way to center text along a path using `Kinetic.TextPath` in Kineticjs.

If not, does anyone know a workaround? I have explored the svg textpath option but not sure how to get this svg into kineticjs.

I have also tried to space the text manually using hair spaces but kineticjs seems to convert the character to a normal space eg. `text.setText(String.fromCharCode(8202))`

Comment: I just checked the source code here: https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/blob/master/src/plugins/TextPath.js and there's nothing in the API to allow centering of text along a path.  Is see you have tried the unsatisfying method of adding leading spaces.  KineticJS has some **very nice** getXY-at-length-on-path functions that you could use to do it yourself.  Text-on-path is made more complex because you have to account for rotation of the characters--a "K" will take up different width on the path based on how the curve requires the "K" to rotate.  Not an easy task!

Comment: Thanks @markE. Can you please tell me which getXY-at-length-on-path functions are available?

Comment: Sure, I posted an answer with the info--mainly because the amount of material wouldn't fit in a comment.  Good coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The standard textpath does not have centering of text along the path**

I checked the source code here: github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/blob/master/src/plugins/… and there's nothing in the API to allow centering of text along a path. Is see you have tried the unsatisfying method of adding leading spaces. KineticJS has some very nice getXY-at-length-on-path functions that you could use to do it yourself. Text-on-path is made more complex because you have to account for rotation of the characters--a "K" will take up different width on the path based on how the curve requires the "K" to rotate.

See how it is done in the existing textpath here: https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/blob/master/src/plugins/TextPath.js

The findSegmentToFitCharacter function (starting line 177) is most instructive.

**These relevant functions can be used to code a do-it-yourself centered textpath**

```
Kinetic.Path.getLineLength
Kinetic.Path.getPointOnEllipticalArc
Kinetic.Path.getPointOnCubicBezier
Kinetic.Path.getPointOnQuadraticBezier
```

So what you'll have to do is:

- Determine the center XY of the path.
- Determine the center of your text (either by width or char-count)
- Draw the last half of your text forward from the centerpoint of the path.
- Draw the first half of your text (in reverse order) backward from the centerpoint of the path.

The findSegmentToFitCharacter nicely shows how to rotate each character at the appropriate angle.

Good coding!  …and I would be interested if you care to share your finished results.

As an aside, whenever I dive into KineticJS source, I am always impressed by their code.

Comment: Thanks @markE, I have never extended KineticJS before so was very interested in that, thanks. I have come up with an acceptable solution for myself http://jsfiddle.net/sEtzy/, though could probably be improved.

Comment: +1 very nice extension!  Would you mind if I grab it for my toolkit too?