# Draw text centered on a curve svg using Kinetic.js

Tags: html, svg, kineticjs

Let me try and explain...

I have a random string (may vary in length) which has to be drawn in a curve. It also has to be centered.

My current code: http://jsfiddle.net/ruPX5/

I used this svg data `M70,70 A50,50 0 1,1 69,70` which creates a circle. As you can see, the text is curved, but not in the center.

I tried using arcs but I don't know how to create a perfect circle with it. Even if I did, I wouldn't know how to get the text in the center..

Is this possible? If so, how would you approach this?

Comment: In the center of what--center stage?  Also, what does it mean when you ask to "create a perfect circle with it"?

Comment: In the center of the textpath. And with a 'perfect circle' i mean, create the same shape you get when using `M70,70 A50,50 0 1,1 69,70`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center text along Kinetic.TextPath with kineticjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010275/how-to-center-text-along-kinetic-textpath-with-kineticjs)

Comment: I just found that post.. i should've searched better before asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Far from perfect, but it'll has to do for now

I'm using rotation for positioning

```
textpath.rotate(-Math.round(textpath.getTextWidth()/2)-10);
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/8kwJm/

Answer (score 0):

According to this question, it's apparently not possible with Kinetic (without some hacking).

[How to center text along Kinetic.TextPath with kineticjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010275/how-to-center-text-along-kinetic-textpath-with-kineticjs)

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution you have not mentioned.

If you use a quadratic curve (with 3 points) to define your curve, you can then pre-set the center point at the center origin, and dynamically push the other two points outwards.

this is my text Update function.

```
        var q = quad;

        var text = handwritingLayer.get('#textpath1')[0];
        text.destroy(); // bye bye

        var SVGdataString = 'M' + q.start.attrs.x + ',' + q.start.attrs.y + ' C' + q.start.attrs.x + ',' + q.start.attrs.y + ' ' + q.control.attrs.x + ',' + q.control.attrs.y + ' ' + q.end.attrs.x + ',' + q.end.attrs.y;   // get (updated) control point data 


       // create a new text path ( you have to each time you change the curve, because the curve is only created when you initially CREATE the text path, after that you cannot change it, thus the 'bye bye' above.

       var textpath = new Kinetic.TextPath({
            x: 0, 
            y: -50,
            id: 'textpath1',
            fill: '#333',
            fontSize: '48',
            fontFamily: 'just-another-hand',
            text: typedText,
            data: SVGdataString
        });

       var textWidth = Math.round(textpath.getTextWidth() );
       var offX =  textWidth  / 2 + 20; // need extra room for the cursor

       q.start.attrs.x = q.center - offX;
       q.control.attrs.x = q.center;
       q.end.attrs.x = q.center + offX;

        // rebuild everything
       // rebuildCircles( quad ); // creates lots of lag, only use if testing

       handwritingLayer.add(textpath);
       pixy.stage.draw();


// basically what this does is...
// every time you type a new Character...
// increase the text string. (typedText).
// calculate its width.
// divide by 2.
// move the left control point (center - width)
// move the right control point (center + width)
// redraw the text path.
```

This is very cool and makes the text path expand as you type, out from the center.
Always keeping the effect 'centered'.

What does 'the effect' mean?

It means, you could define the 3 points as 'lower left' 'middle' 'upper right' or...
'lower left', middle', 'lower right' or
'upper left', middle', lower right

or whatever, and however you define the path, the pattern will not be lost.